# A monotone sequence of sets is convergent

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble understanding the following part of a proof from Leadbetter's measure and probability book:

THEOREM 1.4.2: A monotone increasing (decreasing) sequence {$E_n$} is convergent and lim$E_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^∞ E_n (\bigcap_{n=1}^∞ E_n)$.

Proof:

$$\bar{lim}E_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^∞ (\bigcup_{m=n}^∞ E_m )=\bigcap_{n=1}^∞ (\bigcup_{m=1}^∞ E_m )$$
But $\bigcup_{m=1}^∞ E_m$ does not depend on n and thus, $$\bar{lim}E_n=\bigcup_{m=1}^∞ E_m $$

In particular, I don't understand the logic behind moving from $\bar{lim}E_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^∞ (\bigcup_{m=1}^∞ E_m )$ to $\bar{lim}E_n=\bigcup_{m=1}^∞ E_m $. I understand that $\bigcap_{n=1}^∞ (\bigcup_{m=1}^∞ E_m )$ does not depend on n, but I don't see how removing the intersection wouldn't also change the union of all members of {$E_n$}. Since a monotone increasing sequence of sequences contains more elements per $E_n$ as n increases, wouldn't the union of all subsequences of {$E_n$} also be increasing, whereas the intersection wouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

To see what’s going on, let $A=\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^\infty E_m$; this is simply some fixed set. Then

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left(\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty E_m\right)=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A\,,$$

and no matter how many copies of the set $A$ you intersect, you’re just going to get $A$. Thus,

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left(\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty E_m\right)=A=\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty E_m\,.$$

Comment: Thanks Brian! I appreciate the re-wording and I think I understand now. From my understanding: since each set in an increasing sequence of sets is a subset of the next set, no matter the value of "n" chosen, the infinite union of the sequence will be the same, making the intersection the same.

Comment: @tomhod14: You’re welcome! Yes, that’s correct.